# React hot reload

Tags: reactjs, npm, watch, npm-start

I have started a react project using `create-react-app`, but the hot reload is not working all the time, some times it worked for few minutes, and then stopped and I have to restart the server, and it keeps doing this...
note: using Ubuntu, and the script in package.json is `react-scripts start`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the wrapper, just use the real, hot, webpack dev server.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html

Add the babel-loader and the babel react preset to webpack.config.js, set your entrypoint i.e entry.js, and viola.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be a problem of [Not enough watchers](https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#not-enough-watchers) on Linux.